# What happened inside of (1).toString() and 1.toString() in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript console, if typing below:

```
1.toString();  // Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
(1).toString(); // "1"
```

What is going on inside JS compiler with the two statements?

Comment: We have to tell out whether the dot separates the decimal part or an object property.

Comment: 1.toString() // this will give error because there is no tostring method on primitive datatype Number/interger 
but when you do (1).toString(), then javascript internally do type corresion and convert the number 1 to string "1" and then apply the toString method on it.

Comment: "1".toString();  // "1".  Your understanding makes sense. But what if <code>function(){}()  // Unexpected token. and (function(){}()) // It's OK. </code> Why can't directly invoke anonymous function?@ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: @atul, What about 1.2.toString();  // "1.2"

Comment: @soarinblue actually in mathematics sense a floating number can only have at the most one decimal (.) point, therefore when you do 1.2.toString() then by that logic javascript interpreter automatically treats it as string and hence 1.2.toString() will result as "1.2"

Comment: @atul: What you are saying is not correct. It's true that primitive values don't have methods, but `(1)` is **not** converting the value to a string, which you can easily find out by doing `typeof (1)`.

Comment: @soarinblue: There is no syntax ambiguity in `1.2.toString()`. `1.2` is a number literal, `.toString()` is a method call. `1.toString()` is problematic because the parser expects a digit after the `.`. `1..toString()` works fine as well since `1.` is the number literal and `.toString()` the method call.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`()` is grouping operator, which returns the value of the expression inside it. Here in your case, it's `1`, a primitive number. So it can be boxed to a `Number` object and call its method `toString`.

However for `1.toString()`, the JS engine cannot determine what does `.` mean - a dot operator (for object methods), or a float number point?

To solve this confusion, without the grouping operator, you have two approaches:

- `1 .toString()` // a whitespace, works similar as grouping operator
- `1..toString()` // two dots, in which the second is treated as dot operator

Comment: `1.0.toString()` works too.

Answer (score 14):

`1.toString()` is treating 1 as an integer and expecting number after the **`.`**

In `(1).toString()`, **(1)** is an expression in which a `.` is used to call a method.

Answer (score 3):

Agreed with **@Prajeet** and **@Leo**

As explained in [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) - **Dot notation**

```
1 //Next Line
.toString() //Prints "1"
```

**From Mozilla.org:**
[image]