# Vite React app production build post deployment is giving Invalid or unexpected token error

Tags: reactjs, deployment, frontend, vite

I recently migrated my Create react app to Vite.
App is working fine on local dev, dev deployment, test deployment and stage deployment environments, but when I deployed it on Production, app is giving the following error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DNAQ.png)

Post debugging we found the following code in bundle is giving the error.
[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNrHx.png)

After some research I found the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968598/what-happened-inside-of-1-tostring-and-1-tostring-in-javascript)

But this specific code is introduced when app loads up in browser, but is not present in my bundle.
As well as it only happens in production deployment, lower deployments are working fine.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to :

- Delete the build (dist) folder and create new one, maybe it have some cache.
- Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75619842/vite-build-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-usecont).
- Check that you imported your components correctly, maybe there is a typo.
- add `pdfjs-dist` your **vite.js.config** and rebuild (remove the old build):

```js
 include: [
    "pdfjs-dist"
 ]
```

Comment: Have tried the above things still no success.

Following piece of code is breaking my production build.

`zt = Ut(1.toString);`

Not able to figure out what is introducing it!!

Comment: Can you show me the imported packages/components in the top of the component that my break your app ?

Comment: So post more digging, I found the package creating the problem.

[pdfjs-dist](https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist/blob/master/legacy/build/pdf.js)

Line: 1576.
Code:
`var toString = uncurryThis(1.0.toString);`

In final bundle it is transformed to `zt = Ut(1.toString)`, which is throwing error in production.

Comment: try to include `pdfjs-dist`in your **vite.js.config**, i'll add it to my answer

Comment: Not sure how this will help.

For now I tried [vite-plugin-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-replace).

And used it with following input:

`replaceCodePlugin({replacements: [{from: /1\.0\.toString/g,to:'parseFloat(1).toString',},],})`